# Duplicate 'Unknown Album' listings for the same artist in Music app

Tags: ios, music.app

I am trying to group all songs with no album title (i.e. the 'Album' field for the songs' metadata is empty) for the same artist into one "Unknown Album"

Each song with no album title should be grouped in the same "Unknown Album" album for the artist. Instead each individual song for the artist is split into multiple "Unknown Album" listings (see image)

[image: Example]

What I have tried to fix this:
In iTunes, adding an album title for every song with no album title, then removing the album title.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) I know your question is about the Music app on iOS, but when you say: *What I have tried to fix this: In iTunes, adding an album title for every song with no album title, then removing the album title.*, do you mean you've done this with iTunes on a Mac/PC? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: Thanks for the welcome :) Yes – on a Mac, I have edited the songs' album tag via iTunes. I have tried editing the specific songs stored on my phone, as well as the songs stored locally on my Mac in my iTunes library, then tried adding them to my iPhone after editing their 'Album' field/tag

Comment: Test - in Mac iTunes, show Songs viewed as List, sort on Album. Multi-select all required tracks by one Artist. Cmd/i to Get Info. The only fields that should be filled should be Artist & Album Artist [possibly Genre but untested], in both Details & Sorting tabs. You will know when you have that correct as when you hit OK, the tracks will then all drop to a single 'unknown album' in the list.

Comment: For my local iTunes library, there are no separate 'Unknown Album' listings for an artist. Just the music stored on my iPhone has this problem. (I do not sync my music, I have "Manually manage music and videos" selected in iTunes for my iPhone)

Answer (score 1):

Since you've got access to iTunes on a Mac, the way I would try to achieve what you want is as follows:

1. Launch iTunes on your Mac
2. Ensure you have your music library selected
3. Choose Songs in the lefthand pane
4. You should now see a list of all your songs
5. Filter your list by Artist
6. Now scroll your list so you have the particular artist in view
7. While holding the <kbd>command</kbd> key down click on each of the songs you want to group together - this should highlight them all
8. Now right-click on one of the highlighted songs and select *Get Info* (or just use the <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> shortcut)
9. You'll should get the following prompt:

[image]

10. Click on the <kbd>Edit Items</kbd> button
11. Now start with the Details tab and ensure all fields are blank to begin with and then enter details for Artist, Album and Album Artist) - for album I would replace 'unknown album' with the correct album name (if it exists) or something appropriate like *Cryptic's Freddie Gibbs Compilation*)
12. Then select the Artwork tab and if artwork already exists right-click on it and select the Delete Artwork option
13. Now move onto the Options tab and make sure the media kind is Music (I imagine it already will be)
14. Finally check the sorting tab to make sure that the metadata you completed at Step 11 is reflected within the fields under the Sorting tab
15. When you've finished with all the metadata, click on the <kbd>OK</kbd> button
16. Now sync your iTunes library as you normally would to see if the changes are reflected on your iPhone

**NOTES:**

- If the above doesn't work then try again but at Step 11 ensure you select the Compilation option
- If you have iCloud Music Library and/or iTunes Match enabled, it's unclear how those services *may* impact what you're wanting to achieve, so please report back using comments below to let us know how you go.

Comment: I failed to mention that I do not sync my music, I have "Manually manage music and videos" selected in iTunes for my iPhone. I have tried your suggestion in iTunes with the music stored on my iPhone. For my local iTunes library, there are no separate 'Unknown Album' listings for an artist. Just the music stored on my iPhone has this problem. Also, if I change the album name for each song from nothing (empty/blank field) to something, "Album A" for example, there is still multiple "Album A" listings for the artist

Comment: FIX!!!
I erased my itunes on my iphone with a new mac that had not itunes music stored on it. Logged in with my apple ID. synced. Erased everything. Went back to my primary computer (windows btw) and re-synced. Perfect!